# add weight to order grid

Tags: order-grid

I am trying to add a weight column to my magento order grid (I want the total weight of the order)

I have this part

```
_prepareColumns

$this->addColumn('weight', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Weight'),
        'index' => 'weight',
        'filter_index' => 'sfo.weight',
        'width' => '50px',
    ));
```

The column is shown, but no data is displayed

I think I need to add something in front of `_prepareCollection();`

Does anyone know the correct code for this?

below is the collection part i have already

```
protected function _getCollectionClass()
{
    return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    $table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_shipment_grid');
    //$collection->getSelect()->from('', "((select max(t.created_at) from `$table` as t where t.order_id=main_table.entity_id)) as shipped_date");
    $collection
        ->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(array('t'=>$table), 'main_table.entity_id = t.order_id',array('shipped_date'=>'created_at'))
        ->group('main_table.entity_id');;
    //file_put_contents(basename(__FILE__).".txt",__LINE__.":sql: ".$collection->getSelect()."\r\n",FILE_APPEND);
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('shipping'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
    'main_table.entity_id = shipping.parent_id AND shipping.address_type="shipping"',array('shipping.postcode AS sp'));

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: can you please confirm your collection got correct weight. or sfo.weight is correct filed

Comment: can you please share your collection

Comment: Hi, I don't have one, as when I enter anything, I get an error on the page.

Comment: protected function _prepareCollection()
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('shipping'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
    'main_table.entity_id = shipping.parent_id AND shipping.address_type="shipping"',array('shipping.postcode AS sp'));




        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling wrong table.

there is no field in the name of weight in `sales_flat_shipment_grid`. it is in `sales_flat_order_address`. also please call `'filter_index' => 'sfo.weight'` to `'filter_index' => 'weight'`

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    $table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_order_item');

    $collection
        ->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(array('t'=>$table), 'main_table.entity_id = t.order_id',array('shipped_date'=>'created_at'))
        ->group('main_table.entity_id');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('shipping'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
    'main_table.entity_id = shipping.parent_id AND shipping.address_type="shipping"',array('shipping.postcode AS sp'));

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: Please check it let me know

Comment: if it is work please Accept the answer.  :)

Comment: this is what I have, but its not working, can you give me the whole string?

Comment: $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id' AND'filter_index' => 'sfo.weight' to 'filter_index' => 'weight'array('email'=> 'email', 'weight'=> 'weight' ));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('sales_flat_order_address.address_type', array('eq' => 'billing'));

Comment: Can you give detail in question?

Comment: i updated the code please check it